# How do I get URL parameters from a Flash game (developed with Unity3D)?

Tags: c#, unity, flash, web

I made a simple Flash game in C# using Unity3D. It interacts well with a web page: There is a textbox for the player to type their name and that name is used in-game.

Now I want to pass the player's name into my game as a *URL parameter*. How can I read URL parameters from within a Flash game?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Application.absoluteURL`.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Application-absoluteURL.html

If navigating to the game from another page, they can pass arguments via a `?query-string` that the server can ignore, and that you can parse via string manipulation. If you need to transition to your game without navigating to a new page, you can use an `<iframe>` and do the same.